# Matlab: how to trasform a cell array in a matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cell

Problem:
I have a cell array and every cell of this array has an other cell that contains a string: I want to trasform the cell array in a matrix of strings. How can i do? I have tried to use cell2mat but matlab gives an error: `'Cannot support cell arrays containing cell arrays or objects.'`

Comment: There is no matrix of strings in matlab, there is only a matrix of chars. I assume you want a cell array of strings? Please add some example in- and output to your question to make it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a row cell array of `N` cell arrays of `P` strings:

```
C = {{'abc', 'de', 'f'}, {'g', 'hi', 'jkl'}};
```

then you have 2 ways of organizing the result:

```
R1 = vertcat(C{:});
R2 = horzcat(C{:});
```

When the array is jagged (different lengths of the inner cell arrays of strings) *only one* of the options above will work. If the singleton dimension is different between the cells, *none* of the above options will work.